# RTC : How to handle variants at the component level

Tags: rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

i am trying to work out a method to have component level variants in RTC.
Requirement is that there should be say at least two lines of development for the component. If there is an bug-fix on the parent line, i need to merge that change into the second line. I could not bring up yet a method using the streams. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

2 lines of developments means two stream.

You can easily add, in the flow target of the repo workspace, another stream.

I would recommend adding the parent stream to the flow target of repo workspace on the *second* stream.
That means you would accept changes coming from the parent stream (each time you set that stream in the flow target section as the "current" stream).
Once you have accepted those changes (and merged them in your local workspace or sandbox), you set again your second (and "default") stream as the current one, and are ready to deliver the change set you just accepted back to the second stream.

See an illustration in the section "[How do I use the "new" method to accept from an integration stream instead of delivering to it?](https://jazz.net/library/article/649/#Tips)":

[image]

Comment: We did sort of already tried this and thought it may not be the right way. One Observation is the lack of merge when a changeset is accepted from the parent stream. Consider the the change set contains xyz.c. this file also underwent changes in the variant stream (not changed in current sandbox). Now when we accept the changeset from parent, the file is owerwritten, no merge offered.

Comment: @maxmelbin it is the right way: I always prefer to merge by accepting change set. The only case where a file is just overwritten is when hasn't changed in variant, only in parent. See https://jazz.net/library/LearnItem.jsp?href=content/docs/source-control/mergingbyexample/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I will check that again.